# Commit changes to WordPress Plugin SVN with TortoiseSVN

Tags: plugin-development, svn, repository

I'm trying to upload my plugin for the first time to the WordPress SVN.  I've been granted access from the WordPress team.  I am able to download the directory.  Then I try to place my plugin files into the `trunk` folder, and then commit the changes.  When I do this. I am prompted for my login credentials.  I use the same ones that I use on the Wordpress.org website.  However, it keeps re-prompting me to enter my credentials.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I made a screencast of the process.

http://www.screencast.com/t/3QCfSdyM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your password @ wordpress.org then retry.

If still fails check your firewall log

If it still fails ... ask Andrew Nacin :) http://twitter.com/#!/blamenacin :)

Comment: Funny, I tried this right before I saw your response.  Didn't work though :(

Comment: It might be a firewall issue.  I'm in a corporate setting, and there are all kinds of restrictions on everything.  I'll try it in a different environment later on, and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: I changed it to "https" based on your Firewall comment, and it now works.  Yippee!!

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with this as well, and my solution was to use a different form of the plug-in repository URL.

They give you: `http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/PLUGIN-NAME`

With Tortoise SVN I've successfully used: `http://svn.wp-plugins.org/PLUGIN-NAME`

Give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Same situation.  However, that is a nice tidbit to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the "Save authentication" checkbox...? I had an issue like that, and if I wasn't saving the authentication, I would have to reenter password before every single command or transfer.

Comment: Yup, I've done that.  Same thing.